# Show value based on clicked checkbox?

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to PHP and jquery

There are two tables

maincategory

```
tagId    tagName

4        Gadgets
5        History  
3      Mathematics  
1       Science   
2        Social
```

subcategoryone

```
subOneTagId tagid subOneTagName
1             1    Inventions
2             2    Discoveries
3             1    Timeline
```

`tagid` in subcategory table is same as `tagId` in maincategory.

Here is my PHP Code fetching main catergory

```
<?php 
$res=mysqli_query($con,"select * from maincategory order by tagName") or die("error");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
   echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$row['tagId']."' name='tags[]' id='tag".$row['tagId']."'>   
   <label for='tag".$row['tagId']."'>".$row['tagName']."</label><br>";
}?>
```

Here is another code in the same php page fetching subcategory table based on tagId checked in the main category

`

```
<?php
  $res=mysqli_query($con,
 "select * from subcategoryone order by subOneTagName where tagid='tag".$row['tagId']) 
  or die("error");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))   {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$row['subOneTagId']."' name='subtags[]' 
        id='subtag".$row['subOnetagId']."'> 
        <label for='subtag".$row['subOneTagId']."'>".$row['subOneTagName']."</label><br>";
 }
 ?>
```

The problem is the subcategory table is initially hidden. The subcategory table is the set of checkboxes as you see in the above php code. The subcategory table(which is hidden initially) should show values based on the checked checkbox in the maincategory . So this should happen without refreshing the page. Because both maincategory and  subcategory queries are in the same page.

To be more precise , when I check Science in the maincategory , only Inventions and Timeline from table subcategory  should show up  (refer the above tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for putting your effort for me.

here I found the answer.My JS goes here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSubCategories(element)
    {
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.mainCategory label,.mainCategory input').click(function(){
            var parentDiv = $(this).parents('div:first');
            var tagId = parentDiv.attr('tag-id');
            if(parentDiv.children('input:first').prop('checked') == true)
            $('.subCategoryOne div.tag-id-'+tagId).css('display','block');
            else
            $('.subCategoryOne div.tag-id-'+tagId).css('display','none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I rewrote the subcategory table.

```
<td>
    <?php $res=mysqli_query($con,"select * from subcategoryone order by subOneTagName") or die("error");
                                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                                        {
                                            echo "<div class='tag-id-".$row['tagId']."'><input class='main-tag-".$row['tagId']."' type='checkbox' 
                                                         value='".$row['subOneTagId']."'
                                                         name='subtags[]' 
                                                         id='subtag".$row['subOneTagId']."'> 
                                                  <label class='main-tag-".$row['tagId']."' for='subtag".$row['subOneTagId']."'>
                                                        ".$row['subOneTagName']."</label></div>";
                                        }?>
                                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it without refreshing the page you should look into AJAX (with Jquery) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I am very new to AJAX . Can you please how do I frame it for my situation.